# How to Make Ansible Playbook Wait for Server to Shut Down

Tags: ansible

We have a Jenkins server we are upgrading on a regular basis and are creating a playbook to safely shut the server down, (i.e. shut down after all current jobs are complete) then perform the upgrade tasks. We want our Ansible playbook to wait until the server has stopped responding to connection requests before proceeding. This is the exact opposite behavior of the Ansible [wait_for_connection](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_connection_module.html) module.

We have other similar use cases that involve making sure the service is stopped before working with the files on which it depends. Some of these use cases involve making sure all containers are safely shutdown before spinning up their replacements. Therefore a connection-based approach would be the most reusable for us.

It seems odd that there is not a state on `wait_for_connection` like there is for other modules. It is also odd that this is not a common enough use case to have already warranted such a module.

How do you ensure a service is down/stopped before working on its files?

Comment: Regarding Jenkins, you can simply stop the service if it is correctly registered in systemd (or whatever init system you use). I use this to upgrade a jenkins install holding 500+ projects running on a dozen physical slaves + a kube cluster for on-demand slaves. It works like a charm. Regarding containers, you can easily use the `docker_container` module with `state: absent` prior to running anything else to ensure your containers are off.

Comment: @Zeitounator What happens to build jobs that are currently running? We are hoping to let our server complete currently running jobs before shutting down. Hence, the wait.

Comment: The jobs continue to run on the slaves which catch up when the master comes back up. Since the automated upgrade takes less than 5 mn and is made during low activity hours, nobody generally ever notice it (apart from the fact we communicate everything went smoothly :))

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
  - name: Wait for poweroff
    local_action:
      module: shell
      cmd: "ping -c 1 {{ ipv4 }}"
    register: myping
    failed_when: (myping.rc != 0) and ('100% packet loss' not in myping.stdout)
    retries: 50
    delay: 3
    until: myping.rc == 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @AJAX This is good for a server restart, we could use your approach to wait for the server to restart, then use the `wait_for_connection` for when it comes back up, preferably in a state with no services running other than `ssh`.

We are still looking for a "service" (as in database service) termination; something along the lines of a TCP connection refusal. Your ICMP refusal is clever.

Comment: To check individual service, you can check systemctl status stdout, or, on a lower level, use ansible wait_for module - check for port / stopped option - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html